# Generalization of Sylvester's law of inertia

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we have a symmetric matrix $B$ and an invertible matrix $S$, such that the following holds:  $A = S^TBS$.

Then Sylvester's law of inertia states that the number of negative eigenvalues of $A$ is equal to the number of negative eigenvalues of $B$.

**Question:** Is there some generalization of this result which does not assume $B$ to be symmetric? In particular, I am interested in the case where $B$ is a block diagonal matrix.

**Thoughts:** There is probably no generalization to arbitrary matrices. However, since the theorem holds for a diagonal matrix $B$, I thought that there might be some similar result (maybe weaker) for the block diagonal case.

Comment: Perhaps you already know this, but the reason that the theorem asks for symmetric matrices is that they are guaranteed to have real eigenvalues, so that the notion of negative makes sense. So the first step to generalize to would be to the set of all matrices with real eigenvalues. But that raises the question if $B$ has real eigenvalues, does it automatically follow that $A = S^TBS$ does too (as is the case for symmetric $B$ because it implies that $A$ is symmetric as well) or should we impose that as an extra condition on $A, B, S$? Maybe you can try to answer that first.

Comment: Well, the cases where I know that _A_ has real eigenvalues are if _B_ is symmetric (as you mentioned), or if _S_ is unitary (since then _A_ and _B_ are unitary equivalent and thus similar). If we only assume _B_ to have real eigenvalues, I think that this does not hold. However, I do not know how to check this.There are hardly any theorems which give informations about the eigenvalues of products of matrices.

Comment: If we additionally assume _S_ to have real eigenvalues, then for the same reasons, I would not know how to check if _A_ has real eigenvalues. However my guess would be that the fact that _S^TS_ is symmetric could be helpful.

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Generalizations) has some generalizations of Sylvester's law of inertia that you might find interesting. For instance, there is an answer to this question if we are given that $A,B$ are normal (i.e. $AA^T = A^TA$ and $BB^T = B^TB$).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not useful for the problem I'm working on right now. However it's indeed interesting. Thanks for pointing it out!